# Plant identification help

Tags: houseplants

What's the name of this plant and it's sunlight and water requirements?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Burle Marx Phyllodendron. Example: https://www.monrovia.com/plant-catalog/plants/3847/burle-marx-philodendron/

A hardy plant, likes partial shade and good watering. Can climb or cover the soil. Also likes fertilizers for leafy plants.